# Why does scroll event not trigger when rendering a template in a Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In [this code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/te8LQ/1/), a Backbone view is bound to a pre-existing DOM element.  The scroll event triggers as expected.

In [this alternate sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hKWR9/), the Backbone view renders the HTML instead of using a pre-existing DOM element.  The scroll event doesn't fire.

Why?

The primary difference is the second sample does this:

```
this.$el.html(template);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/hKWR9/1/

```
$(function(){
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'scrollbox',
        events: {
            'click': 'onClick',
            'scroll': 'onScroll'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.render(); 
        },
        render: function() {
            var template = '<div class="filler"></div>';
            $('body').append(this.$el); 
            this.$el.html(template);

        },
        onClick: function() {
            console.log('click');
        },
        onScroll: function() {
            console.log("scroll");
        }
    });

    var App = new MyView();

}());
```

Your fiddle doesn't work, because you defined your el with classname `.scrollbox`, while it should have been `scrollbox`. There doesnt seem to be a benefit in creating another 'scrollbox' within this '.scrollbox'.